# Installing Service Bus for Windows Server

Tags: servicebus, azureservicebus

I am looking at the diagram at [Service Bus For Windows Server : Supported Topologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj193006%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

My question is, in 2 tier deployment, can i install Service Bus Gateway on Machine1, Service Bus Broker on Machine2 and Windows Fabric on Machine3 or that diagram means i install all these 3 components on same machine and have 3 machines like that and create a farm?

Also i am little confused as what do they mean by "Service Bus Host"? Does it mean a system that has Service Bus Gateway, Service Bus Broker and Windows Fabric (all 3 components) installed on it or just Service Bus Broker?

Answer (score 1):

You must install all 3 components together on one node. You can decide to put the databases on another server but the services get installed together.

Therefore the term service host probably would mean all three.